# Inflating Android list subviews -> duplicate IDs

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have some content in an Android app which is shown in a list.  Each list entry has similar fields - let's say a picture, some text, and a text box.  However, some list entries are different than others.  The order of the content is based on the result of a server call.

The list itself needs to be fairly dynamic, and I'm currently using a linearlayout rather than a listview for a few reasons.  My code looks something like this:

```
LinearLayout list = findViewById(android.R.id.list);

while (more content to add) {
    switch (content type) {
        case A:
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type_a, list, false);
            EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
            // Do stuff with editText
            list.addView(v);
            break;
        case B:
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type_b, list, false);
            ....
    }
}
```

This works great.  Except - when I put this in a fragment, and rotate the screen, now my app crashes because I have multiple fields with the same `android.R.id.edit` identifier.

I had thought this was a fairly elegant solution and the Android gods seem to disagree.  Do I need to rip out the ID for all of my xml sublayouts?  If I go this route, how should I grab references to the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So obviously, `ListView` or `RecyclerView` would be preferable to use here, but since you've stated you have reasons not to, I'd suggest that you disable automatic state saving for each of the views.

You can just call `editText.setSaveEnabled(false)`, which will fix the issue, but have the side effect of not automatically retaining the view's state (e.g. input data will be lost). If you're maintaining this data yourself and restoring it on configuration changes or state restoration, this should be a totally workable solution.

I believe you could also just call `setSaveFromParentEnabled(false)` on the containing `LinearLayout` (although I haven't used that flag myself), which should disable state saving for *any* view in the sub-hierarchy. Same caveat applies.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't do this but my question has got very little views and I have no idea how to do it so would you be able to take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729545/reflection-in-background-android) please? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Thank you, in the end this is the solution I went with.  I spent some time going back and trying to use a ListView again, but ran into many (well-documented) issues with putting EditText in a ListView and Android's focus system.  Stack Overflow contains many potential fixes, but I couldn't get any of them to work across all versions of Android I need to support.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `ListView` instead of the `LinearLayout` and creating a custom `adapter` to fill the `ListView`. You could still have the `list_item` layouts that you have and then add them to the list in the `newView` method of your `adapter`. Pass your **content type** through a method, say `getItemViewType()`. Something like this:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Choose the layout type
    int contentType = getItemViewType();
    int layoutId = -1;
    switch (contentType) {
        case A: {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type_a, list, false);
        EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
        // Do stuff with editText
        list.addView(v);
        break;
        }
        case B: {
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type_b, list, false);
        ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I tried this approach, but ran into issues with EditText in ListView when trying to change focus.  See my comment on @kcoppock's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occur due to device screen rotation

When the phone rotates and the screen changes orientation, Android usually destroys your application’s existing Activities and Fragments and recreates them. Android does this so that your application can reload resources based on the new configuration.

The most important aspect of handling orientation changes is saving state. In most cases this involves implementing the **onSaveInstanceState** method (this could be in your Activity, Fragment or both) and placing the values you need to save in the Bundle argument that gets passed to the method.

For more details and code examples...
[Please read this article](http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic list, you should be using a ListView or RecyclerView.